# android things i2c avc denied

Tags: android, i2c, android-things

I am studying Raspberry Pi 3 by android things dp 5.1.

I build and play sample sources which is androidthings weatherstation.

(https://github.com/androidthings/weatherstation)

I cannot playing app and below logs.

I cannot use i2c on RP3 by android things 5.1?

How to fix this?

---

pin connection picture:

[image: pin connections picture.]

upside picture for BME280:

[image: upside picture for BME280.]

downside picture for BME280:

[image: downside picture for BME280.]

---

logcat at launching application:

```
10-30 19:05:31.307 23-23/? I/kdevtmpfs: type=1400 audit(0.0:155): avc: denied { create } for name="i2c-1" scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
10-30 19:05:31.307 23-23/? I/kdevtmpfs: type=1400 audit(0.0:156): avc: denied { setattr } for name="i2c-1" dev="devtmpfs" ino=33671 scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
10-30 19:05:31.317 23-23/? I/kdevtmpfs: type=1400 audit(0.0:157): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/i2c-1" dev="devtmpfs" ino=33671 scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
10-30 19:05:31.317 23-23/? I/kdevtmpfs: type=1400 audit(0.0:158): avc: denied { unlink } for name="i2c-1" dev="devtmpfs" ino=33671 scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
10-30 19:05:31.347 2153-2153/com.example.androidthings.weatherstation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.androidthings.weatherstation, PID: 2153
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidthings.weatherstation/com.example.androidthings.weatherstation.WeatherStationActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing BMP280
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing BMP280
        at com.example.androidthings.weatherstation.WeatherStationActivity.onCreate(WeatherStationActivity.java:205)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: com.google.android.things.pio.PioException: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: I/O error (code 5)
        at com.google.android.things.pio.I2cDeviceImpl.readRegByte(I2cDeviceImpl.java:81)
        at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.bmx280.Bmx280.connect(Bmx280.java:174)
        at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.bmx280.Bmx280.<init>(Bmx280.java:152)
        at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.bmx280.Bmx280SensorDriver.<init>(Bmx280SensorDriver.java:54)
        at com.example.androidthings.weatherstation.WeatherStationActivity.onCreate(WeatherStationActivity.java:199)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: I/O error (code 5)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1956)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
        at com.google.android.things.pio.IPeripheralManagerClient$Stub$Proxy.I2cReadRegByte(IPeripheralManagerClient.java:1465)
        at com.google.android.things.pio.I2cDeviceImpl.readRegByte(I2cDeviceImpl.java:79)
        at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.bmx280.Bmx280.connect(Bmx280.java:174) 
        at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.bmx280.Bmx280.<init>(Bmx280.java:152) 
        at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.bmx280.Bmx280SensorDriver.<init>(Bmx280SensorDriver.java:54) 
        at com.example.androidthings.weatherstation.WeatherStationActivity.onCreate(WeatherStationActivity.java:199) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Things is encountering an error trying to open the I2C device connection: `I/O error (code 5)`.

This could happen if you have another app running that has already opened the same I2C bus, or if a wiring problem is preventing the device from communicating successfully with the peripheral.

From the pictures you've taken, SDA/SCL seem to be in the right place, but you are providing 5V to a sensor that is only rated to accept 3.6V maximum. You might try powering the sensor from Pin 1 instead of Pin 4.

Comment: I cannot solve this issue. the application can open i2c device. but can not read byte at address 0xD0 yet. I try to read byte after removed other sensors. but not resolved. Good news is sometimes read byte and working well.

Comment: I added relay to bme280 ground. so.. working well..[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pzfwct855wGglHaPYGTqYA8SBY8i_dI1/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Here is My code for BMP280 Sensor Using Android Thing BMX280-Driver,
before using this code please make sure your wire connections are correct.

```
class BMP280Activity : Activity() {

    private var mBmx280: Bmx280? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmp280)

        //mBmx280 = Bmx280("I2C1", Bmx280.DEFAULT_I2C_ADDRESS) // This line is 
        //creating issue with some sensors....

        mBmx280 = Bmx280("I2C1", 0x76) //Need to test on sensor before using....
        mBmx280?.temperatureOversampling = Bmx280.OVERSAMPLING_1X
        mBmx280?.pressureOversampling = Bmx280.OVERSAMPLING_1X
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        tv_temp.text = "${mBmx280?.readTemperatureAndPressure()?.get(0)} And ${mBmx280?.readTemperatureAndPressure()?.get(1)}"
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        mBmx280?.close()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```